# Only import certain column with importdata in Matlab

Tags: matlab, nan, text-processing

I have a formatted textfile. Somehow, when I use importdata it stops after some lines when NaN occurs. Now I only want to import a certain column, because I know, there won't be any NaN. Is it possible to only read a certain column with importdata or to avoid that it stops after the occurrence of NaN?

Thanks!

```
A B C
t1 0.1 ---
t2 -1 0
t3 0.3 ---
```

Delimiters are single spaces. If I import it to Excel, every column in my textfile has its own column in the Excel file.
In this example, I would only want to import column B so that I would have in the struct .data

```
0
-1
0.3
```

Comment: Share with us some sample of your input data, so as to give us idea about the delimiter(s) used and if possible the expected output too.

Comment: Are you looking for a struct output?

Comment: Any output is okay, as long as it returns all rows of the specific column. Maybe it isn't formatted with single spaces, because I tried `textscan(fid, ' ')` and got the error: Badly formed format string.

Comment: Also, `A B C` is the first row of the text file that is to be omitted from the final output, right?

Comment: And, the first number in your sample expected output must be `0.1` and not `0` I think. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**Importdata Approach**

For a cell array output, you may use this -

```
a1 = importdata(filepath,'%s') %//' filepath is the path to your text file
s1 = regexp(a1,'\s','Split')
out = cellfun(@(x) x(:,2), s1(2:end)) %// expected output as a cell array
```

If you want to have a double array as output, use this after the above code -

```
out = str2double(out)
```

**Textscan Approach**

```
fid = fopen(filepath,'r'); %//' filepath is the path to your text file
d1 = textscan(fid,'%s %f %s','HeaderLines',1);
out = d1{1,2} %// out is expected output as a double array
fclose(fid);
```

**Edit 1:**

```
a1 = importdata(filepath,'%s') %//' filepath is the path to your text file
s1 = regexp(a1,'\s','Split')

s1 = s1(cellfun(@numel,s1)>1) %//' removes rows like `---` or empty lines
out = cellfun(@(x) x(:,2), s1(2:end))

out = str2double(out);
out = out(~isnan(out))  %// expected output as a double array
```

Comment: I can't do a vertcat because the dimensons are not consistent. But I think I can fix it now by iterating over all the cell arrays and catching the right column.

Comment: @Baloo And fixed the code for `importdata` too to make it work for inconsistent sizes too!

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't solve my problem, because I have columns with Strings like "This is a String" so the delimiter %s doesn't work. I am wondering that such an easy task like importing only one column can be such a big deal.

Comment: @Baloo It becomes a big deal because you can't use a fixed delimiter for such inconsistencies. `importdata`, `textscan` and other such file reading tools rely on delimiters. To sort out your issue (assuming you are not getting any error, but an output with strings and numbers mixed), try this workaround. After you use the `importdata approach`, add this - `out = str2double(out); out = out(~isnan(out))`

Comment: The problem is, that importdata stops the import after the appearance of --- in one row where it expects a number. It also changes the other numbers to NaN in this row. I will try write a bash script that changes the --- to 0. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Baloo Check out **Edit 1**!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this in a more general way.
You say

> "Somehow, when I use importdata it stops after some lines when NaN occurs."

So do not use importdata but use textscan directly. (under the hood importdata is basically a wrapper around textscan to make your life easy, but if importdata fails you need to use textscan .)

It has all these parameters you can set:

```
CollectOutput, CommentStyle, DateLocale, 
Delimiter, EmptyValue, EndOfLine, 
ExpChars, Headerlines, MultipleDelimsAsOne, 
ReturnOnError, TreatAsEmpty, Whitespace, TextType
```

If even textscan fails you need to use `fgetl` and work the lines, but let's hope you don't need it.

Try this code:

```
fid = fopen('test.txt');
data=textscan(fid,'%s %f %f','Delimiter',' ','TreatAsEmpty','---','Headerlines',1);
fclose(fid);
```

`Data{2}` will be your second column